# Kubenates RunAsUser is forbidden

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, kubernetes-security

when I try to create a pods with non-root fsgroup (here 2000)

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: security-context-demo
spec:
  securityContext:
    runAsUser: 1000
    fsGroup: 2000
  volumes:
  - name: sec-ctx-vol
    emptyDir: {}
  containers:
  - name: sec-ctx-demo
    image: gcr.io/google-samples/node-hello:1.0
    volumeMounts:
    - name: sec-ctx-vol
      mountPath: /data/demo
    securityContext:
      allowPrivilegeEscalation: true
```

hitting error

```
Error from server (Forbidden): error when creating "test.yml": pods "security-context-demo" is forbidden: pod.Spec.SecurityContext.RunAsUser is forbidden
```

Version

```
root@ubuntuguest:~# kubectl  version
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"10", GitVersion:"v1.10.2", GitCommit:"81753b10df112992bf51bbc2c2f85208aad78335", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2018-04-27T09:22:21Z", GoVersion:"go1.9.3", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"10", GitVersion:"v1.10.2", GitCommit:"81753b10df112992bf51bbc2c2f85208aad78335", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2018-04-27T09:10:24Z", GoVersion:"go1.9.3", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
```

Can any one help me how to set ClusterRoleBinding in cluster.

Answer (score 0):

If the issue is indeed because of RBAC permissions, then you can try creating a ClusterRoleBinding with cluster role as [explained here](https://github.com/kubernetes/dashboard/wiki/Creating-sample-user).

Instead of the last step in that post (using the authentication token to log in to dashboard), you'll have to use that token and the config in your `kubectl` client when creating the pod.

For more info on the use of contexts, clusters, and users [visit here](https://darshanadiga.github.io//kubernetes-context-setup/)

Answer (score 0):

Need to disable admission plugins SecurityContextDeny while setting up Kube-API

On Master node

```
ps -ef | grep kube-apiserver
```

And check enable plugins

```
--enable-admission-plugins=LimitRanger,NamespaceExists,NamespaceLifecycle,ResourceQuota,ServiceAccount,DefaultStorageClass,MutatingAdmissionWebhook,DenyEscalatingExec
```

Ref: [SecurityContextDeny](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/admission-controllers/#securitycontextdeny)

Answer (score 0):

```
cd /etc/kubernetes

cp apiserver.conf apiserver.conf.bak

vim apiserver.conf
```

find `SecurityContextDeny` keywords and delete it.

```
:wq 

systemctl restart kube-apiserver
```

then fixed it